# Sequentially rename batch files with Python by sorting them according to their creation time

Tags: python, file-rename, batch-rename

I need to sequentially rename batch files by sorting them according to their creation date and time. The first name should be started from 1001 and it should be increase by 1. To do this I have got a sample code from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rename-multiple-files-using-python

It renames filenames randomly. But I need to do it according to file creation date and time. How can I do it?

If anyone suggest VBScript or PowerShell it will be also highly appreciated.

```py
import os


def main():
    folder = "xyz"
    for count, filename in enumerate(os.listdir(folder)):
        dst = f"1001{str(count)}.jpg"
        src = f"{folder}/{filename}"  # foldername/filename, if .jpg file is outside folder
        dst = f"{folder}/{dst}"

        os.rename(src, dst)


# Driver Code
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Advance thanks for your help.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`os.path.getctime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getctime) to get the creation time and sort accordingly.

Here is an example snippet that works:

```py
import os

def main():
    folder = "xyz"

    files = os.listdir(folder)
    files.sort(key=lambda x: os.path.getctime(f"{folder}/{x}"))

    for count, filename in enumerate(files):
        dst = f"{1001 + count}.jpg"
        src = f"{folder}/{filename}"  # foldername/filename, if .jpg file is outside folder
        dst = f"{folder}/{dst}"

        os.rename(src, dst)


# Driver Code
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You may substitute `os.path.getctime` with [`os.path.getmtime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime) to sort by last modification time instead.

Comment: The `f"{1001 + count}.jpg"` isn't equivalent to `f"1001{str(count)}.jpg"`.

Comment: @martineau that was intentionally done. (because OP has said "_started from 1001 and it should be increase by 1_")

Comment: not "_start with_"

Comment: Sorry, I was just comparing code…what you're doing it right.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tibebes. M. Last four days I was trying do this job using various renaming utility. But none of them were working perfectly. So I've decided to do it using Python and you have given me the perfect solution. Wishing your best of luck.

Comment: @AbuSahama thanks, I am very glad to hear that :) please consider upvoting/accepting it as an answer.

Comment: @Tibebes. M, I've tried to upvote. It gives me the following message:

QOUTE
Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.
UNQOUTE

Comment: @AbuSahama oh understood :) you can accept the answer instead then (the checkmark)